# How to use a react class property in another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, properties, jsx

I have a property in a react component (**Createjob.js**):

```
class Createjob extends Component {
.....
  handleClick = clickType => {
    const {currentStep} = this.state
    let newStep = currentStep
    clickType === 'next' ? newStep++ : newStep--
    if (newStep > 0 && newStep <= 6) {
      this.setState({
        currentStep: newStep
      });
    }
  }
}
export default createjob
```

and I have a button in another react component and I want it to use this property
someting like:

```
export class MainInfo extends Component {
<button type='submit' onClick={() => this.Createjob.handleClick('next')} className='next'>ادامه</button>
....
}
```

how to achieve this?

Comment: What's the relationship between those components? Give more context.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I just wanted to import the CreateJob class (from the CreateJob.js) into my button component (Button.js) and use it like my example on the top but Im not sure if its the correct approach

Comment: It's definitely not, no. You probably need to lift the state to a shared parent, or to a state container like Redux.

Comment: Is there any relationship between `Createjob` and `MainInfo` components?

Answer (score 1):

pass the **handleClick** fucntion as a prop to the another component:
as:

```html
<Component handleClick={this.handleClick} />
```

then in your button code :
 **this.props.handleClick('next')} className='next'>ادامه**

Answer (score 0):

If your button is inside a child component of your Createjob component, you can achieve this by passing the handleClick function as a prop to the child component.

```html
  const Createjob = () => {
  
    ....
    const handleClick = clickType => {
      const {currentStep} = this.state
      let newStep = currentStep
      clickType === 'next' ? newStep++ : newStep--
      if (newStep > 0 && newStep <= 6) {
        this.setState({
          currentStep: newStep
        });
      }
    }
    ...
    
   return <ChildComponent onClick={handleClick} />
 }

const ChildComponent = ({onClick}) => <button type='submit' onClick={() => onClick('next')} className='next'>ادامه</button>
```

Comment: I edited my question, could you please look at it now?